# Create a 301 Redirect / Rewrite Rule For A Specific URL In Wordpress Via htaccess File

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Trying to create a custom rewrite rule in the `.htaccess` file in WordPress for the following URL:

```
https://example.com/products-pages/?product_search=apples
```

to

```
https://example.com/products-pages/?product_search=apples&items_per_page=all
```

This can be done using the following:

```
Redirect 301 /products-pages/?product_search=apples      https://www.ourwebsitedomain/product_search=apples&items_per_page=all
```

However, there is a slight flaw in this.

The word "apples" shown in the above example is a search word that the customer / website user has inputted in our custom search box (this is a custom live search feature, and not the built in Wordpress default search system.

We need to be able to create a rewrite rule / 301 redirect or similar setup, which allows for any search term to be inputted, e.g: if "oranges" or "pears" or any word is typed in the search, this will get copied across and implemented in the redirect.

Have searched through this site, and various other forums, and can't find anything that helps so far.

If anyone has any suggestions, please let us know.

Tried a function in functions.php, which did not work.

Have also tried the following, which didn't work:

(added the following line of code:)

```
<input type="hidden" name="items_per_page" value"all">
```

full code section below, with above line of code added:

```
function wpsc_live_search() {
if ( version_compare( get_option ( 'wpsc_version' ), 3.8, '<' ) ) {
    $autocomplete = 'onkeyup="autocomplete(event)"';
} else {
    $autocomplete = '';
 }
//get the url to submit the search to
$product_page_id = wpsc_get_the_post_id_by_shortcode( '[productspage]' 
);
$pp_url = get_permalink( $product_page_id );
// the js below listens for the enter keypress and redirects to the 
  product page with a get var of the search term
 ?>
 <div class="live_search_form">
<input type="hidden" name="items_per_page" value"all">
<input name="product_search" id="wpsc_search_autocomplete" <?php echo 
$autocomplete; ?> class="wpsc_live_search" autocomplete="off" 
placeholder="Search …"/>
<label></label>
<script type='text/javascript' > /* <![CDATA[ */
jQuery('#wpsc_search_autocomplete').keypress( function(e){
if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
var url = '<?php echo $pp_url ?>'+'? 
product_search='+jQuery(this).val();
url = encodeURI(url);
jQuery(window.location).attr('href', url);
}
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
<div class="blind_down" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
<?php   
}
```

Comment: So how does the user navigate to that first URL - simply by submitting the form? Then why don't you simply add a `<input type="hidden" name="items_per_page" value"all">` to your form, instead of trying to redirect the request?

Comment: Thanks for that. Already tried that yesterday, with no luck. Appreciate the help though.

Comment: _"Already tried that yesterday, with no luck"_ - that is absolutely not a useful problem description. // If you really insist on solving this via a redirect - then go look into how to use a `RewriteCond`, to check on query string contents.

Comment: @Cbroe - have added details of what didn't work on this above.

Comment: That doesn't work, because you are not letting the form submit normally, but are using JavaScript to assemble the target URL. So instead of adding the hidden input field, just append `&items_per_page=all` to the assembled URL directly then.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. Apologies for being a bit vague on my earlier response about it not working. I do appreciate your help and advice. Would this be the part of code that I need to amend? Not sure how to amend this? url = encodeURI(url);
jQuery(window.location).attr('href', url);

Comment: `var url = '<?php echo $pp_url ?>'+'?product_search='+jQuery(this).val()+'&items_per_page=all';`

Comment: CBroe you're a genius! That works perfectly! Really appreciate all your help and effort!

Comment: _Aside:_ "This can be done using the following:" - No you can't. The `Redirect` directive matches the URL-path only, so the directive as posted would not do anything (it will never match). `value"all">` should obviously be `value="all">` (missing `=`) - you appear to have copied this verbatim in your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be handled via a redirect - but adding the extra parameter directly on the client side to begin with, spares one extra HTTP request.

You have a form there that gets submitted via JavaScript when the user hits the enter key, so the parameter can just be added to the URL that gets assembled in that process:

```
var url = '<?php echo $pp_url ?>'+
          '?product_search='+jQuery(this).val()+'&items_per_page=all';
```